# How to Calculate Accuracy of multiple Pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix, forecast

I have multiple pandas dataframes as follow:

```
data1 = {'1':[4], '2':[2], '3':[6]}
baseline = pd.DataFrame(data1)

 # baseline output  
   1  2  3
0  4  2  6

data2 = {'1':[3], '2':[5], '5':[5]}
forecast1 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# forecast1 output
   1  2  5
0  3  5  5

data3 = {'1':[2], '3':[4], '5':[5], '6':[2]}
forecast2 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# forecast2 output
   1  3  5  6
0  2  4  5  2
```

How can I calculate the accuracy (or confusion matrix) of **forecast1** and **forecast2** (separately) compared to the **baseline** dataframe (i.e. baseline vs forecast1 and baseline vs forecast2) ?

please also note that forecast1 and forecast2 might have some extra columns compared to the baseline dataframe. So, the accuracy calculation needs to consider the numbers of the available columns and deal with the extra columns as well. Is there a way to deal with such case?

These dataframes are a result of data cleaning that I am doing and that is why some of them have few extra columns not available in the baseline dataframe.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: [here] is not clickable

Comment: Is this for time-series data? Both the confusion matrix and accuracy classification metrics. You need RMSE or MAE for instance. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html) for more

Comment: I looked at something similar to these. but I want to report a percentage in my report and that is why I am trying to calculate accuracy out of the two dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(baseline.columns)
print(forecast1.columns)
print(forecast2.columns)
```

```
Index(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='object')
Index(['1', '2', '5'], dtype='object')
Index(['1', '3', '5', '6'], dtype='object')
```

You can take the intersection of the columns to find out which columns are common between baseline and forecast and just apply accuracy_score on those columns.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

common_columns = list(set(baseline.columns).intersection(forecast1.columns))

avg_acc = 0.0
for c in common_columns:
    c_acc = accuracy_score(baseline[c], forecast1[c])
    print(f'Column {c} acc: {c_acc}')
    avg_acc += c_acc/len(common_columns)

print(avg_acc)
```

Write a function to take baseline and a forecast to give you accuracy.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def calc_acc(baseline, forecast1):
    common_columns = list(set(baseline.columns).intersection(forecast1.columns))

    avg_acc = 0.0
    for c in common_columns:
        c_acc = accuracy_score(baseline[c], forecast1[c])
        print(f'Column {c} acc: {c_acc}')
        avg_acc += c_acc/len(common_columns)

    print(avg_acc)
    return avg_acc
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def calc_acc(baseline, forecast1):
    penalize = True
    common_columns = list(set(baseline.columns).intersection(forecast1.columns))

    avg_acc = 0.0
    for c in common_columns:
        c_acc = accuracy_score(baseline[c], forecast1[c])
        print(f'Column {c} acc: {c_acc}')
        if penalize:
            div = len(common_columns) + abs(len(forecast1.columns) - len(baseline.columns)) # it will penalize for both having more or less columns than baseline, you can change it based on your needs
            avg_acc += c_acc/div
        else:
            avg_acc += c_acc/len(common_columns)

    print(avg_acc)
    return avg_acc
```

For regression try mean absolute error, the lower the error the best the prediction is.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, mean_absolute_error

def calc_acc(baseline, forecast1):
    penalize = True
    common_columns = list(set(baseline.columns).intersection(forecast1.columns))

    avg_acc = 0.0
    for c in common_columns:
        c_acc = mean_absolute_error(baseline[c], forecast1[c])
        print(f'Column {c} mean absolute error: {c_acc}')
        if penalize:
            div = len(common_columns) + abs(len(forecast1.columns) - len(baseline.columns)) # it will penalize for both having more or less columns than baseline, you can change it based on your needs
            avg_acc += c_acc/div
        else:
            avg_acc += c_acc/len(common_columns)

    print(avg_acc)
    return avg_acc
```

Usually, mean percentage correct is approximately 100% - mean error. So, you can just subtract the error from 100%.

```
def perc(a_list, b_list):
    ans = 0.0

    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        ans += (1. - abs(a_list[i]-b_list[i])/a_list[i])

    return ans

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, mean_absolute_error

def calc_acc(baseline, forecast1):
    penalize = True
    common_columns = list(set(baseline.columns).intersection(forecast1.columns))

    avg_acc = 0.0
    for c in common_columns:
        c_acc = perc(baseline[c], forecast1[c])
        print(f'Column {c} mean percentange correct: {c_acc}')
        if penalize:
            div = len(common_columns) + abs(len(forecast1.columns) - len(baseline.columns)) # it will penalize for both having more or less columns than baseline, you can change it based on your needs
            avg_acc += c_acc/div
        else:
            avg_acc += c_acc/len(common_columns)

    print(avg_acc)
    return avg_acc
```

Comment: Thanks furcifier, I am getting zeros for all columns in avg_acc

Comment: Also, how to penalize for having extra columns? this method is only ignoring the forecast extra unnecessary predictions

Comment: because your accuracy is zero, none of the values are same.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to penalize for extra columns. I'm adding to answer.

Comment: I played a bit with the numbers. The issue with the accuracy_score function is that it wants the prediction to be exactly the same and does not consider the closeness of the prediction to the actual. So, if the prediction is 99 and the actual is 100, it gives it a score of 0 instead of 0.99

Comment: Hmm, yes it should. Is it a regression problem? Or a classification?

Comment: It is a kind of regression. I am using something very complicated to come up with the numbers. but what is really important is how to calculate the closeness of the prediction to the actual numbers in the actual. So, these numbers are continuous numbers and are not classifications.

Comment: Updated with mean absolute error, it's a much better metric for regression problems. Some of the other regression metrics are available here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: I looked at it earlier but I wanted to calculate it manually because I want to report a percentage instead of an error number.

Comment: Usually, mean percentage correct (regression) = 100% - mean percentage error, I have updated with a new answer this may solve your problem.